# Cities Skylines Warehouse Income

Tags: cities-skylines

In Cities Skylines the Industry DLC added warehouses. The first one you can access I believe is the warehouse yard and as you progress through the game you get bigger options.

My question is, on the budget tab if you go to the industries sub-tab you can see that warehouses have an expense and income associated with them. I assume the expense is the cost of paying employees to work the warehouse.

But where does the income come from? Mine seems fixed at $0.00 for my single warehouse. I thought maybe it was tied to how much it exported stocked supplies but I don't think it is that. I have a huge amount of exports and the warehouse is full of them (generic goods) and it stays at $0.00 for income.

Answer (score 1):

Warehouse has 3 options:

- **Fill** - *expense* - Just storing goods to max capacity - also import goods if needed
- **Empty** - *income* - Stored goods are exported asap
- **Balanced** - *50:50* - exporting everything above 50% capacity and vice versa

I only use **Fill** for importing goods that I cannot acquire myself. **Balanced** is good buffer if your own production is not fast enough. **Empty** for everything else.